# DRF: AttributeError when trying to creating a instance with SlugRelatedField and double underscore in slug_field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I get this error as the instance is successfully created and saved in the database with POST request and DRF:

```
AttributeError: 'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'user__username'
```

Here is my **UserProfile** and **UserImpression" models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path, null=True, blank=True)
    imp_laptop = models.ManyToManyField(Laptop, related_name="laptop_impression", through="UserImpression", through_fields=('profile', 'laptop'))

    objects = models.Manager()
    custom_manager = UserProfileCustomManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + ' profile'

class UserImpression(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    laptop = models.ForeignKey(Laptop, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    liked = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
          models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['profile', 'laptop'], name='unique_profile_laptop_impression'),
        ]
```

My serializer class **UserImpressionSerializer**:

```
class UserImpressionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=UserProfile.objects.all(), slug_field="user__username")
    laptop = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=Laptop.objects.all(), slug_field="slug")

    class Meta:
        model = UserImpression
        fields = ['profile', 'laptop', 'liked']
        validators = [
          UniqueTogetherValidator(
              queryset=UserImpression.objects.all(),
              fields=['profile', 'laptop']
          )
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
      
      profile = validated_data.get("profile", None)
      laptop = validated_data.get("laptop", None)

      if profile is None:
        raise serializers.ValidationError(
          {"profile": "Cannot retrieve the profile instance with the username"}
        )
      if laptop is None:
        raise serializers.ValidationError(
          {"laptop": "Cannot retrieve the laptop instance with the laptop slug"}
        )
      liked = validated_data.get("liked", True)
      return UserImpression.objects.create(profile=profile, laptop=laptop, liked=liked)
```

In my **view**:

```
class UserLikeDislike(generics.CreateAPIView, generics.UpdateAPIView, generics.DestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, TokenHasReadWriteScope]
    queryset = UserImpression.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserImpressionSerializer
```

My goal for the **profile** field is to get the **UserProfile** instance through the **username** field in the **User** model which has a 1-1 relationship with **UserProfile** model.

Any helps or suggestions would be appreciated! Any other directions to get to my goal would be also great as well!

Comment: can you share your view?

Comment: @ruddra I just added the view that uses the serializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned in the question:

> the instance is successfully created and saved in the database with POST request and DRF

Meaning save is working fine, but returning response is failing. This happened because `SlugRelatedField` tries to get the data using `getattr` directly via `slug_field` ([source](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/relations.py#L466)). It will cause error because there is no field named `user__username` for the `UserImpression` object.

Hence I would suggest to override `to_represenation` function of the RelatedField, like this:

```
class CustomField(serializers.SlugRelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value.user.username

class UserImpressionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = CustomField(queryset=UserProfile.objects.all(), slug_field="user__username")
```

### Update

---

As my [PR#8922](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/8922) has been merged, I expect this bug to be fixed in next release (from [`3.15`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/milestone/78)).

Comment: thank you so much for the solution. After applying your codes, it works fine without causing the error. If you have the time, can you elaborate more about "GET request is failing" even though I use POST ?

Comment: I think i have the put wrong terms here. What happens after you make a post request, it stores the data and then sends a response with the serializer, this when the request fails or failed